# The C++ template with inheritance/template issue

Tags: c++

I have stuck with the following code in some project (it is simplification).

```
template <class X >
class A {
  public:
    int a;
};

class Y;
class B : public A<Y> {
  void foo() {a = 0;}
};

template < class D >
class C : public A<D> {
  void foo() {a = 0;}
};
```

The compiler fails with:

```
test.cpp:14:14: error: ‘a’ was not declared in this scope
```

Why in the C::foo the compiler fails to recognize A::a and in B::foo does not? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` is a dependent base class member in `B`, you need to access it with `this->a`.